# Why does this C macro function calculating sum of 2 numbers generate error?

Tags: c, macros

I have a piece of code to calculate sum of 2 numbers using `#define` below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define sum(a, b) \
    int res = 0;    \
    res += (a + b); \
    (res ? res : 0)

int main () {
    printf("%d ", sum(3, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled upper code, I caught this error:

```
error: expected expression before 'int'
     int res = 0;    \
note: in expansion of macro 'sum'     
     printf("%d ", sum(3, 4));
```

So, what did this error mean? And, how can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: A macro is text replacement. If you can't copy/paste the code into the place where you use the macro then the macro won't work there. Use a function.

Comment: BTW: `res ? res : 0` is exactly the same as `res` :-) it only gives `0` when `res` is already `0`!

Comment: @pmg: I am pretty sure that `res ? res : 0` places a double extra guarantee on the addition, following the first extra guarantee of `int res = 0; res += …`. You would not want to just do the addition in one step, shocking the processor. You have to warm it up with a little initialization.

Comment: There's a reason most experienced programmers try to stay away from complex macros, and rely on functions instead. Modern compilers are good at inlining functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your program through C preprocessor like `gcc -E program.c` then you will have following towards end:

```c
int main () {
    printf("%d ", int res = 0; res += (3 + 4); (res ? res : 0));
    return 0;
}
```

which is invalid code.

To fix this you need to fix the macro for `sum`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define sum(a, b) ((a) + (b))

int main () {
    printf("%d ", sum(3, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

You need to use parentheses to counter against potential misuse of operator precedence for operators like ++ or --. It is not a problem here but in general it is a good practice.

A better choice would be to write an inline function for this kind of work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for pointing that out. It seems I am losing my C/C++ as I have not programmed in those for more than 7 years now. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I got it!

Answer (score 0):

If you use GCC then it has a non-standard and therefore non-portable extension that allows [*statement expressions*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), which allows you to put multiple statements in an expression.

I don't really recommend its use, but it is possible to do what you want as a macro:

```
#define sum(a, b) \
    ({ int res = 0;    \
       res += (a + b); \
       (res ? res : 0) })
```

But the proper solution is to use functions instead, and rely on the compiler to properly inline it (with a little "hint" from you):

```
inline int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```